# Pandas How to compare the comma separated column values with comma separated column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am comparing comma sep column values with comma separated column from two different dataframe
My dataframe which is looking like as below

df1=

```
      col1
    0.35,0.35
    0.23,0.53
    0.08,0.73
    0.2,0.47
    0.36,0.53
    0.27,0.42
    0.16,0.75
    0.33,0.39
    0.3,0.57
    0.59,0.29
    0.08,0.8
    0.06,0.9
    0.5,0.27
    0.09,0.78
    0.16,0.68
    0.11,0.75
    0.04,0.88
```

df2=

```
     col1   col2
 1.03,0.03  0.68,0.0
 0.23,0.53  0.20,0.50
 0.27,0.42  0.27,0.42
 0.16,0.75  0.16,0.75
 0.59,0.29  0.50,0.20
 1.02,0.03  0.67,0.0
 0.59,0.29  0.45,0.25
 1.02,0.03  0.67,0.0
 1.01,0.03  0.66,0.0
```

`condition= df1[df2["col1"] <= df1["col1"] & df2["col2"] >= df1["col1"]]`

output should look like

```
     col1
  0.16,0.75
  0.27,0.42 
  0.59,0.29
```

Basically this are the X and Y axis comma sep values respectively, I have range df2 col1 and col2 between this range I want values from the df1  column,
my original data is looking as in the link [original data file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PprA_-qS-ciGFfQdf13ksDJPf0d5vGpc?usp=sharing)

Comment: You should explain how you reach the output. The logic for obtaining the output

Comment: What does `<=` mean when comparing two strings or float tuples?

Comment: @anky I have provided the condition. may be it will work. I am not able resolve because of comma seperated values

Comment: @piRSquared this are the int values two datapoints from the X and Y axis, for comparision I made it comma separated

Comment: Maybe there's a typo, conditions must be wrapped in parenthesis, i.e. `df[(cond1)&(cond2)]`. Also... are DataFrame of the same size?

Comment: @MaxPierini dataframe of different size

Comment: if `df1` and `df2` have different sizes you cannot subset `df1` with a condition of `df2` because especially if `df2` is smaller than `df1` you'd get an `IndexingError`

Comment: @MaxPierini we can't loop also?

Comment: You have to better define what you're looking for